# How to call filebrowser in HUE

Tags: python, hadoop, cloudera, hue

I'll start by saying that I'm very new to HUE and Python and have no prior experience with either.

What I have to do now is make my own HUE application to upload files to HDFS, start an oozie work flow by passing parameters trough my application and finally monitoring this job.

I can't find any guides or tutorials online, and the Cloudera documentation is extremely limited.

To narrow down my question:

Is there a way to upload files trough my application using the existing upload functions provided by the file browser?

I started to look into the code of the filebrowsers but it's a bit too complex for a noobie like me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hue lets you reuse its libraries and you can even re-use existing pages with a CURL.

You can look at the [SDK](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-3.6.0/index.html) and Hue [Programming section](http://gethue.com/category/programming/) in the blog.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Romain, but the SDK documentation is a bit to basic and vague for a starter like me, I have tried using it in combination with the Cloudera Quickstart VM with very little success.